# UIView isHidden function, what does "the view's next valid key view" means?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm currently studying the `isHidden` method of `UIView` class.

In the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden), it mentioned

> Hiding the view that is the window’s current first responder causes
>   the view’s next valid key view to become the new first responder.

I was just wondering, what does `the view's next valid key view` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is apparently left over from the older [`NSView` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483369-ishidden) and **it is incorrect**.

`NSView` is the macOS equivalent of iOS's `UIView`. `NSView` has a `nextKeyView` property which indicates what view should get keyboard focus when the user tabs out of the current view. `NSView` also has a computed property, `nextValidKeyView`, which is the next view in the key view loop that accepts first responder and is not hidden.

`UIView` has no `nextKeyView` or `nextValidKeyView` property.

Furthermore, on iOS, hiding the current first responder does **not** cause “the view’s next valid key view to become the new first responder”, for any reasonable definition of “next valid key view”, because **the hidden view remains first responder**.

Here's a demo, recorded on a real iPhone 6 (not the simulator) running iOS 10.3.2. The “Button” toggles the `isHidden` property of the top text field.

[image: demo]

After I type “hello” in the top text field, I tap the button to hide that text field. The keyboard is still active but the second text field has no blinking insertion point. I then type “world” and tap the button again. The top text field reappears, and now it says “hello world”. It continued to be first responder while it was hidden. The second text field (which is the only possible candidate for “next valid key view”) did not become first responder.

Comment: oh wow, I'm simply amazed by your answer. How did you know stuff that even the apple people got wrong?

Comment: I guess what I was trying to ask is, how did you get to where you are, in terms of ios developement? Is it just hard work and a lot of time, or you have your own way of learning?

Comment: Insatiable curiosity, the willingness to dive deep, and a memory for details. I've watched tons of WWDC videos, read a lot of documentation, written many tests, and disassembled many library functions. Also, I have been programming since 1980. Good luck!

Comment: haha, as I expected, hardwork x  time = awesomeness. Thanks again for helping out!  Can't appreciate it enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Causes that the next valid key (the next view of the stack) will be the responder, which if there is nothing "behind" that view that you are hiding will be the super view.

Comment: Thanks Cristina for helping out! Correct me if I'm wrong, but judging from what you said, I think the next valid key means "whatever if behind the hidden view" (it could be the hidden view's super view or it could be a sibling view that is behind the hidden view, whichever is first view behind the hidden view). I hope my understanding is correct

Comment: and why is it called the "next valid key view"? Is there any reason behind the choice of wording, as far as you know?

Comment: That is correct. "whatever if behind the hidden view" but maybe the supper view for example could be hidden as well so will not be a valid key.

Comment: This is not what happens in my testing.